# Offline app : Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, offline

I want to create windows phone 8.1 silverlight app in offline mode.

Is there any way?
Please tell me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with `offline mode` ? If you don't want to use the internet, don't use it.

Comment: Benjamin, I have to call web services, and have to show it. I don't have much knowledge but how is it possible with local database. Thanks

Comment: Then you should cache your data you get from the webservices.

Comment: Benjamin, how to do it? Can you show me by a code? Thats is why I can understand it properly. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's impossible to add code, because your question is so open-ended. I've put an answer that shows you the high-level design that should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer which will show you code, but just the high-level design that could be possible.

1. You want to display some data
2. Check if you have internet

   2.1 If you do, check if you want to update (do you update every time you can, or do you update every X tries, X seconds, ...)
   2.1.1 When you fetch the data, store it in a file or database.

   2.2 If you don't, check if you have the result in a file or database
3. Show the data you got in step 2.

Comment: Thats good, but how would I get data without internet, that you described in step 2. Thanks brother!!

Comment: @NiteshKothari you wouldn't. IF you want to get your data for the first time, and you have no internet, you **can not** show any data!

Comment: Benjamin, is it possible with sqlite database or local? Thanks for ur time.

Comment: @NiteshKothari That is just an implementation choice for you. Really, that's why we can't give any code. Because it's all dependant on your choices.